# Roll-Down then Roll-Up on page load

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to have a div roll down on page load, pause for a couple seconds, then roll up and close. Similar to the advt banners we see on cnn.com and other websites. How I do accomplish that? I tried to do the following in document.ready, but not able to get it to work. Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function rolldownDiv(){

           if ($('#feature-content').is(":hidden"))
           {
                $('#feature-content').slideDown().delay(10000);
           } else {
                $('#feature-content').slideUp().delay(10000);
           }
           return false;        
}

rolldownDiv();
});
```

And I have following css for the "feature-content" div:

```
/* Mozilla ignores crazy MS image filters, so it will skip the last line in the
following */
#feature-content {
    float:left;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='images/transparent.png');
    display:none;
}

/* IE ignores styles with [attributes], so it will skip the following. */
#feature-content[id] {
    float:left;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url(images/transparent.png);
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly "isn't working," but if you want to delay the animation you need to change

```
$('#feature-content').slideDown().delay(10000);
```

to

```
$('#feature-content').delay(10000).slideDown();

// or
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#feature-content').slideDown();
}, 10000);
```

If you want the animation to slide up on its own:

```
$('#feature-content').slideDown().delay(10000).slideUp();
```

---

Why is the `if ($('#feature-content').is(":hidden"))` check needed? How could the `#feature-content` element *not* be hidden at document ready? If it's an issue with the CSS, this should work just fine:

```
#feature-content {
    float:left;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url(images/transparent.png);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='images/transparent.png');
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feature-content').slideDown().delay(10000).slideUp();
}
```